# How to get javascript "link-rotator" functionality from body to division?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Would anybody be able to make an "in-div"  (as opposed to "in-body") version of the following web page?

http://squareoftwo.com/

In other words, I want this functionality as a part of a bigger web page, with a frame around the rotator, white space left and right from the frame and possibly other information above and beneath the frame.

- The page should have a vertical scrollbar and the frame -and the words in it- should respond (reposition) upon moving that scrollbar.
- Any (part of) words crossing the frame border should be invisible.
- If the mouse is not positioned in the frame, the words should not rotate.

I have tried several things, but I always completely mess up the result (I'm far from a javascript expert).

Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Of course we'd be able to make it, but we're not free-of-charge rent-a-coders :). What have you tried so far? Post some code with a specific question and you can get some help getting that code working. It just looks like a tag cloud, there's heaps of jQuery plugins available for that: http://blog.templatemonster.com/2011/02/16/jquery-tag-cloud-solutions/

Comment: Sorry if I took anyone for free-of-charge coding slaves... It would take me very far trying to explain what I already did. But thanks to your link, my problem seems solved anyway. I wasn't aware of the fact those kind of link rotators were generally known as (rotating) tag clouds. It indeed seems my problem was dealt with by others before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following blog post seems to provide a very good answer:

http://www.gabrielpillet.com/en/blog/2/2010/08/22/creating-a-3d-cloud-tag-with-jquery-jquery-accessibility-php-seo-development-css